# Contribution fault current data to CSV

Tags: python, api, fault, psse

I am using IEEE39 bus data.If only bus_1 fault in system. I can use `pssarrays.ascc_currents` to see the contribution current of other buses.But I don't know how to use python to save other buses contribution current one by one data to CSV. 
I use psse ver34 & python 2.7.
I have this small code:

```
psspy.short_circuit_units(1)
psspy.short_circuit_coordinates(1)
sid = 3
all = 0
rprtyp = 2 # or 3 
rprlvl = 0 # number of contribution levels
fltbuses=[1]
psspy.bsys(sid,0,[0.0,0.0],0,[],len(fltbuses),fltbuses,0,[],0,[])
rlst = pssarrays.ascc_currents(sid,all,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1.0,"","","",rprtyp,rprlvl)
```

In psse the answer is:

```
    AT BUS_1  /FAULTED BUS IS:  1 / 0 LEVELS AWAY
     FROM                /I+/       AN(I+)  
SYNCHRONOUS MACHINE      /1898.3/   -63.96 
      2                  /3332.5/  -102.76      
     39                  /6649.2/   -87.59   
 INITIAL SYM. S.C. CURRENT(I''k) /11605.3/   -88.14
```

I know total three phase fault current api is `rlst.flt3ph.values()`
fault bus api is `rlst.fltbus`

I can't find the corresponding api code about contribution current.
I want to print these data to csv.

```
    [SYNCHRONOUS MACHINE][1898.3][-63.96]
          [2][3332.5][-102.76]
         [39][6649.2][-87.59]
[total 3ph fault current][11605.3][-88.14]
```

Thanks in advance!